# iSearch module not working in Open Cart

Tags: ajax, search, module, opencart

I'm trying to use iSearch in my homepage. I've completed the steps in the documentation and it's enabled, but when i try to search for something, the ajax live search results are not displaying. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Is it a free and open-source extension or a commercial extension?

Comment: Free and open source

Comment: No it's not free it's $44.99 so contact the developer: iSense.

Comment: @RumenPanchev are you referring to this module? https://isenselabs.com/products/view/isearch-intelli-sense-search  It's not `FREE` that's a paid module